# Reflection of the Flutter FutureBuilder Change

Tags: flutter, request

With FutureBuilder, I'm doing a listing process by making an api get request. Again, I update a field by making put request on the same screen.

How can I update this changed field in the UI? **I want the change I made to be shown immediately.**

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: futurePosts,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index) {
    Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.55,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(snapshot.data[index].title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17, height: 2.1, decoration: snapshot.data[index].isCompleted ?  TextDecoration.lineThrough : TextDecoration.none),),
                                        Text(snapshot.data[index].content, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, height: 2),)
                                      ],
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

isCompleted = false normally. It is true when I click the button. And when the text is true, it is crossed out. When I renew the application, the text is crossed out. How can I do this when I clicked the button?